# Removing all except underscore and hyphen symbols for a text file in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, tokenize

I want to remove all the special characters (including the single lower case  alphabets) for an input file except the words having underscore symbol (_) and hyphen (-) symbols (example added) using with or without regex for an unflattened list (list of lists)?

Does there exist any way?

```
import re
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

data = {'fresh air', 'entertainment system', 'ice cream', 'blood pressure', 'body temperature', 'car', 'ac', 'air quality'}
data = {i: i.replace(" ", "_") for i in data}
pattern = re.compile(r"\b("+"|".join(data)+r")\b")

text_file = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions', 'www.google.com/the pda', 'Z\'s is (vitamin-d) in (milk) 5 ml "enough", carrying? 321 active automatic body hi+al blood pressure.', 'body temperature [try] to improve air quality level by automatic intake of fresh air.', 'blood pressure monitor', 'I buy more ice cream', 'proper method to add frozen wild blueberries in ice cream']
sw0 = (stopwords.words('english'))
sw1 = ["i", "hi"]
sw=sw0+sw1
result = [pattern.sub(lambda x: "{}".format(data[x.group()]), i) for i in text_file]
tokens = [[word.lower() for word in word_tokenize(word)] for word in result]
filtered_tokens = [[token for token in sentence if (token not in sw)] for sentence in tokens]
print(filtered_tokens)
```

Input is shown in the text file in the code.

I want the output to display only the words (preserving some words with underscore in between, like body_temperature, blood_pressure, air_quality etc.).

I have tried and completed using `regexp_tokenize` with a `regex pattern` and setting the `gaps = True`. I want to achieve the same using nltk `word_tokenize`. Any help is appreciated.

Expected Output:

`[['pda'], ['vitamin-d', 'milk', 'ml', 'enough', 'carrying', 'active', 'automatic', 'body', 'blood_pressure'], ['body_temperature', 'try', 'improve', 'air_quality', 'level', 'automatic', 'intake', 'fresh_air'], ['blood_pressure', 'monitor'], ['buy', 'ice-cream'], ['proper', 'method', 'add', 'frozen', 'wild', 'blueberries', 'ice_cream']]`

Comment: I am sorry but your question is not making much sense. What does the list `data` have to do with your task? You seem to remove some words because they contain punctuation characters (`google.com`, `is's`), but in other cases you strip the punctuation and keep the word (`"enough,`, `(vitamin-d)`). No program can read your mind and guess what you want for each word. Please figure out an explicit rule if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks Alexis for pointing this out. I am showing some part of a large program, data, lists etc. with a notion that the original file may contain upto this much complexities. The data for the text file have been extracted from wikipedia containing several complex symbols like (“, ”), mathematical characters and languages other than English (chinese: 智能拨号). I am showing some of it. May not be necessary that the original file should contain the same. Anyway thanks for your concern, I am trying on my own and will report, if something productive is achieved.

Comment: Good luck. Getting regex matches out of a nested list of strings is no big deal, but nobody can help you solve your problem if you cannot figure out how to express it. (So consider formulating a version of the problem that shows what you have trouble with -- is it the iteration over nested lists, or the detection of the words matching specific criteria?)

Comment: Yeah you are right @alexis